# Splitting a list of words from a text file into an array in BASH

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, scripting

I've been fighting with this a lot this past hour or so, I'm trying to get a text file filled with names into an array of those words.

The text file is formated:

`Word1~~Word2
 Word1~~Word2`

..
Eventually I want to split up these words into 2 arrays of word1 and word2 breaking at the "~~" but that is a problem for later

Right now I (currently) have this:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=$(cat ~/words.txt)
c=0

for word in $a
do
    arrayone[$c]=(echo $word)
    c=$((c+1))
done
```

I've tried many many other ways and all either don't work or error out upon execution, I'm relatively new at BASH and am having extreme difficult with the syntax

Thank you for your time

Comment: [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). Read [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for various ways to do this safely.

Comment: Also, run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ before posting here, which would point out (among other things) BashPitfalls #14: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually just as easy to solve your "later" problem right now. Unless you need to be able to deal with words with (unpaired) literal `~` characters, this will do:

```
declare -a arr1=() arr2=()
while IFS='~' read -r word1 _ word2; do
  arr1+=( "$word1" )
  arr2+=( "$word2" )
done <file

printf 'Words in column 1:\n'
printf '  %s\n' "${arr1[@]}"

printf 'Words in column 2:\n'
printf '  %s\n' "${arr2[@]}"
```

If you *do* need to deal with the more interesting case, treating only a double tilde as special, one approach to doing so is with a regex match:

```
while IFS='' read -r line; do
  if [[ $line =~ (.*)[~][~](.*) ]]; then
    arr1+=( "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" )
    arr2+=( "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" )
  else
    printf 'Line does not match pattern: %s\n' "$line" >&2
  fi
done <file
```

Comment: Upon doing the declare statement I get the same error I get when I try most things I've tried recently from this site: 'test.sh: 5: test.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected' Also, what is <file?

Comment: Is your shell really bash? Using `#!/bin/sh` or `sh yourscript` means you're running POSIX sh, not bash; POSIX sh doesn't have arrays at all.

Comment: What's the output of `echo "$BASH_VERSION"`, if placed in your script?

Comment: Thats what I thought, its bash v. 4.3.11(1), maybe I'm going about running it wrong? i do 'sh test.sh' in the terminal

Comment: (Also, because bash scripts *are not* POSIX sh scripts, naming them with `.sh` extensions is bad form -- it implies that someone could run `sh yourscript`, which won't necessarily work. Best practice is not to put filename extensions on scripts at all -- they define commands, and you don't run `ls.elf`, after all).

Comment: Yeah. `sh test.sh` explicitly runs POSIX sh; that is indeed Doing It Wrong. Just name it something like `myscript` (as the name `test` is already taken by the standard test command), give it the executable permission, and rely on your shebang to correctly select an interpreter. When you run `sh yourscript`, you're overriding the `#!/bin/bash` it starts with.

Comment: That made it work, thank you.  Is there any thing I can look up to understand what exactly you did with your code to make it work? I'm very ignorant on the syntax.  To me bash syntax, is more difficult than C syntax

Comment: Reading the BashGuide from the beginning (the document I linked into) is a good idea -- but that said, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 is a directly on-point starting place.

Comment: ...really, both the links Etan suggested in the first comment on the question are good ones.